# How to Pandas fillna() with mode of column?

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have a data set in which there is a column known as 'Native Country' which contain around 30000 records. Some are missing represented by `NaN` so I thought to fill it with `mode()` value.  I wrote something like this:

```
data['Native Country'].fillna(data['Native Country'].mode(), inplace=True)
```

However when I do a count of missing values:

```
for col_name in data.columns: 
    print ("column:",col_name,".Missing:",sum(data[col_name].isnull()))
```

It is still coming up with the same number of `NaN` values for the column Native Country.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just call first element of series:

```
data['Native Country'].fillna(data['Native Country'].mode()[0], inplace=True)
```

or you can do the same with assisgnment:

```
data['Native Country'] = data['Native Country'].fillna(data['Native Country'].mode()[0])
```

Answer (score 9):

Be careful, NaN may be the mode of your dataframe: in this case, you are replacing NaN with another NaN.

Comment: Pandas 0.24.0+ does not count NaN by default: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__)
```

> 1.2.0

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': [np.nan, 'France', np.nan, 'Spain', 'France'], 'Purchased': [np.nan,'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', np.nan]})
```

|  | Country | Purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | France | Yes |
| 2 | NaN | Yes |
| 3 | Spain | No |
| 4 | France | NaN |

```
 df.fillna(df.mode())  ## only applied on first row because df.mode() returns a dataframe with one row
```

|  | Country | Purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | France | Yes |
| 1 | France | Yes |
| 2 | NaN | Yes |
| 3 | Spain | No |
| 4 | France | NaN |

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': [np.nan, 'France', np.nan, 'Spain', 'France'], 'Purchased': [np.nan,'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', np.nan]})

df.fillna(df.mode().iloc[0]) ## convert df to a series
```

|  | Country | Purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | France | Yes |
| 1 | France | Yes |
| 2 | France | Yes |
| 3 | Spain | No |
| 4 | France | Yes |

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want to apply on multiple columns at once

Answer (score 1):

If we fill in the missing values with `fillna(df['colX'].mode())`, since the result of `mode()` is a Series, it will only fill in the first couple of rows for the matching indices. At least if done as below:

```
fill_mode = lambda col: col.fillna(col.mode())
df.apply(fill_mode, axis=0)
```

However, by simply taking the first value of the Series `fillna(df['colX'].mode()[0])`, I think we risk introducing unintended bias in the data. If the sample is multimodal, taking just the first mode value makes the already biased imputation method worse. For example, taking only `0` if we have `[0, 21, 99]` as the equally most frequent values. Or filling missing values with `False` when `True` and `False` values are equally frequent in a given column.

I don't have a clear cut solution here. Assigning a random value from all the local maxima could be one approach if using the mode is a necessity.

Comment: After running this code, in my case, there remains NA values in the dataset. `pandas` version 1.5.2

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number 'mode' or any other strategy

1. for mode:

```
    num = data['Native Country'].mode()[0]
    data['Native Country'].fillna(num, inplace=True)
```

2. for mean, median:

```
    num = data['Native Country'].mean() #or median(); No need of [0] because it returns a float value.
    data['Native Country'].fillna(num, inplace=True)
```

or in one line like this

```
data['Native Country'].fillna(data['Native Country'].mode()[0], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who came here (as I did) to fill NAs in multiple columns, grouped by multiple columns and have problem that mode returns nothing, where there are only NA values in the group:

```
df[['col_to_fill_NA_1','col_to_fill_NA_2']] = df.groupby(['col_to_group_by_1', 'col_to_group_by_2'], dropna=False)[['col_to_fill_NA_1','col_to_fill_NA_2']].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]) if len(x.mode()) == 1 else x)
```

you can fill any number of "col_to_fill_NA" and make group by any number of "col_to_group_by".
The if statement returns mode if mode exists and returns NAs for the groups, where there are only NAs.

Answer (score 0):

So, I note that `df.mean()` returns a `pd.Series` whereas `df.mode` called on a dataset with mixed types (both numeric and categorical in my case) returns a `pd.DataFrame` with the same columns as `df` and row 0 giving the mode.
This is expected because a Series' type must be unique, but still causes `df.fillna(df.mode())` to fail where `df.fillna(df.mean())` works.

Here is a one-liner to circumvent the issue in this case:

```py
df.fillna({k: v[0] for k, v in df.mode().to_dict().items()})
```

Another issue is still that the first value `v[0]` is selected among a possible list of modes, as pointed out by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60065025/5118757), but this can still be improved by applying another aggregation function to `v`.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:
`fill_mode = lambda col: col.fillna(col.mode())`
and for the function:
`new_df = df.apply(fill_mode, axis=0)`

Comment: [Audris Ločmelis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60065025/5118757) already provides a better answer in this case.